# Bell's Theorem - Why does $\lambda$ have a probability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, determinism, bells-inequality

I'm reviewing Bell's theorem. In his proof by contradiction, he assumes the world is deterministic and defines a vector $\lambda$ as the set of all hidden variables which play a role in determining the spin of each entangled electron. He then starts to speak about the "probability density function of $\lambda$", called $\rho (\lambda )$.

But if the world is deterministic, then $\lambda$ is nonprobabilistic; it is a delta function at precisely the values which the hidden variables take. What is the purpose of introducing a density function at all?

Comment: $\lambda$ is assumed to be a function, then defined for all values of the hidden variables and returning always the same value. It is also assumed to be an isotropic function. Indeed this class of theories may be discarded. From what I understood, EPR were wrong but anyway this proves anything on the need of a magic adjustment between the 2 sides. $\lambda$ may be a  not-function , meaning it returns different/random results at each test for the same argument, miming the superposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bell does not assume that the universe is deterministic. He assumes that it is described by a local hidden variable theory. These are not the same thing.

Bell explains this himself by giving an example of a successful hidden variable theory. To briefly recap his argument: take an ensemble of spin 1/2 particles, each in the state $(| \uparrow \rangle+|\downarrow \rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. A measurement of whether the spin of any given particle will be up or down is random and will never be described by a single-valued hidden variable.

However, this system *can* be described by a local hidden variable theory, if you allow the hidden variable to be distributed with some probability. Bell does exactly this. Specifically, he shows that for a hidden variable that is distributed with an even probability distribution along the hemisphere (on a Bloch sphere) where $\vec{\lambda} \cdot \vec{p}>0$, $\vec{p}$ being the vector describing the spin state of the particle, there is a theory in which this hidden variable correctly reproduces the probability distribution of measurement results for any measurement axis one could choose. In his paper, Bell then goes on to prove that there is no similar theory for more than one particle.

Now, one could imagine that this probability distribution over $\lambda$ is due to a fundamental randomness as in regular quantum mechanics. One could also suppose that it is due to ignorance about the initial conditions of some deterministic system, like the probability distributions that one makes for the outcomes of a coin flip. Bell's inequality is general enough to cover both cases, as long as this hidden variable is local (in the sense that Bell uses this term). The lack of assumptions about $\lambda$ is one reason that this result is so important.

Comment: Exactly.  The point of Bell's Theorem is not that quantum observables can't be deterministic; it's that they can't be classical random variables.

Comment: The only problem is Bell never gave a successful example of a hidden variable theory. It wasn’t even realistic.

Comment: @BillAlsept Bell was motivated in developing his theorem by Bohemian pilot wave theory, which is a nonlocal hidden variable theory. I'll leave it to others to judge whether it is 'successful' or not.

Comment: @Rococo Einstein‘s original thought experiment would’ve considered correlating particles that have more than one variable such as polarization. A particle can do more than that.